# SUMIF / LOOKUP for Capacity Planner

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two sheets, the first lists by week resources (A) and their capacity (E) in hours. I would like to add a demand (F) column by week for each resource.

Demand is to be derived from another sheet, where I have a list of tasks assigned to a resource (E) - each task has a start and end date, a derived effort, and an effort per week (M) - this effort per week is added to a week column to show load by week.

I used a sumif to get the demand by resource for a given week but now that this plan goes out 18 months I cannot autofill the sumif formula and cannot get a sumif to work with a lookup. There has to be a way to lookup demand on the second sheet, sum and populate on the first...

Is there a way to populate the demand on the first sheet without entering the SUMIF formula in each column?

Comment: @pnuts **precisely** - I'd accept a different approach if there is one. Thanks!

Comment: @pnuts yes, through to end of June 2018

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply put in F3:

```
=SUMIF(Load!$E$1:$E$9999, $A3, INDEX(Load!$1:$9999,,MATCH(C$1,Load!$2:$2,0)))
```

This can be copied to all other "Demand"-locations. ;)